# ORA-000932 When joining an xmltype to a varchar field

Tags: oracle, t-sql, join, oracle11g, xmltype

a little backstory, i have a comma delimited column in a database, that i have tried to convert into a many to many junction table, so instead of having

```
ID REPORT
1   5,6,7
```

i would see

```
ID REPORT
1    5
1    6
1    7
```

the query below does just that, and seems to work correctly,

```
 with t as (select id,hqcat from report)
SELECT id, EXTRACT(column_value,'/e/text()') hqcat from t x,
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<ROW><e>'||REPLACE(hqcat,',','</e><e>')||'</e></ROW>'),'//e')))
```

however   when i try to join it to my lookup table by hqcat, i get a ORA-00932 error about inconstant data types, please help me, how do i change my original query to make it work with other tables and joins?

here is the join causing the error:

```
select *
from    BIN03   a11
    join    (  with t as (select id,hqcat from report)
SELECT id, EXTRACT(column_value,'/e/text()') hqcat from t x,
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<ROW><e>'||REPLACE(hqcat,',','</e><e>')||'</e></ROW>'),'//e')))) a12
      on    (a11.CODE = a12.HQCAT);
```

Thank you!

i've also tried to create my new "many to many" view as so:

```
WITH TAB AS 
( (select id ID, hqcat STR from report))
SELECT ID as ID, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR (STR, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) HQCAT  FROM TAB 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (regexp_count(str,',') + 1);
```

but this just reduces query speeds by 1000's.....

Answer (score 0):

The [(deprecated) extract function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm) returns an XMLType, not a `varchar2`. You can cast it to the type you want, either in the inline view:

```
cast(EXTRACT(column_value,'/e/text()') as varchar2(3))
```

or when comparing the value:

```
a11.CODE = cast(a12.HQCAT as varchar2(3))
```

I've guessed the variable size you need, obviously, you might need it to be different. You could also use [the XMLType `getStringVal()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71974) as shown below.

It seems little odd to mix an old-style cross join with a comma in the inline view's from clause, with ANSI joins in the rest, and you can get odd (or hard to debug, anyway) results doing that. You could also use another CTE for clarity:

```
with t as (select id, hqcat from report),
a12 as (
  select id, extract(column_value,'/e/text()').getstringval() hqcat
  from t
  cross join table(xmlsequence(extract(xmltype('<ROW><e>'||
    replace(hqcat,',','</e><e>')||'</e></ROW>'),'//e')))
)
select *
from a12
join bin03 a11 on a11.code = a12.hqcat;
```